# How to remove event listener of an element when I remove the corresponding element in the midst of the event being triggered in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to remove event listener of an element when I remove the corresponding element in the midst of the event being triggered in D3?

Right now, after I call `.remove()`, it seems like the event is still lingering.

For example, I have an event listener that listens for mousedown, if I mousedown all the time and remove the corresponding element using my keyboard, the mousedown event still lingers. Is this expected?

More specifically, I am dealing with the d3.drag() function which my element calls.

If so, is there a way to clear all of them at once or do I need to remove them manually? How to remove the lingering event?

The following is the link to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/38wtj4y0/33/

Try dragging the rectangle around and **not release your mousedown**. Press a key and the rectangle will disappear but when you move your mouse around (still mousedown), you will see that the console is still printing "dragging"

***Update***

@Gerardo Furtado's answer below is still a workaround hack, which is to make all triggered function return using the if statement. In other words, if the user does not release mousedown, behind the scene, this drag function will still be triggered forever, just that they will all do nothing since they will return. This is still an utter waste of resource.

The only explanation that I can think of that causes this problem is that D3 can only remove an event listener if it is no longer active, i.e it has to wait for user to release. Therefore, I need a way to free all triggered user interaction.

Comment: The callback may keep running, but there is no listener anymore (afaik). Please, use the snippet (the `<>` button) to reproduce the issue, so we can see what's happening.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Is the callback supposed to keep running? Removing this running callback is essential to the proper functioning of my application. What do you mean by the <> button?

Comment: Pls share your code.

Comment: @user136266 It depends on the callback. Edit your question adding a running code. The `<>` button is the 7th button from the left in the top bar.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Added code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question, although I have to admit, that I have never come across this problem in a real world application. The reason why this happens is to be found in the inner workings of D3's drag implementation.

First, it is worth mentioning, that, if you remove an element from the DOM tree, it can no longer become a target when performing hit-testing for a pointer event. Thus, no event listener registered on that element will be executed any more. This is the behavior one would expect and it is the reason for your confusion, because in your JSFiddle the listener seems to executed even though the element was successfully removed.

To understand what is going on, you have to dig into the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/src/drag.js) of `d3.drag()`. On initialization the drag behavior [registers](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/src/drag.js#L40-L41) various event handlers on the selection's elements:

```
function drag(selection) {
  selection
      .on("mousedown.drag", mousedowned)
  //...
}
```

This handler listening for `mousedown` events will not set up the rest of the drag behavior before such an event is fired on the respective element. Once an element of the drag behavior receives a `mousedown` event, the internal [`mousedowned()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/src/drag.js#L50-L61) handler will be executed:

```
function mousedowned() {
  //...
  select(event.view).on("mousemove.drag", mousemoved, true).on("mouseup.drag", mouseupped, true);
  //...
}
```

Within this handler a `"mousemove.drag"` and a `"mouseup.drag"` listeners are registered on `event.view`. This [`view`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/view) property of the `MouseEvent` is inherited from the [`UIEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent) interface and—at least in browsers—points to the `Window` object the event happened in. Those drag handlers on the global `window` are used by d3-drag to do its work. And those handlers are responsible for the seemingly confusing behavior you witnessed. We will come to this soon, first let us check how the listeners are subsequently removed.

When the drag gesture eventually ends by firing a `mouseup` event, those handlers are removed from the `window` object in the function `mouseupped()`:

```
function mouseupped() {
  select(event.view).on("mousemove.drag mouseup.drag", null);
}
```

Now, let us have another look at your code. Even though you removed the target for the drag behavior triggered by a `keydown` event, the aforementioned handlers on the `window` still exist because you are keeping the mouse button pressed whereby suppressing a `mouseup` event to be fired. Hence, the `mouseupped()` handler has not yet been executed. This will keep the drag behavior alive as `mousemove` events are still captured by the drag's internal handlers on `window`. Additionally, those internal handlers will also keep delegating to your own `dragged` handler causing the console output you are witnessing.

As mentioned at the very beginning of this post, I have never seen this causing any real world trouble. If you nonetheless want to avoid this behavior you could remove the internal handlers once you remove the target:

```
d3.select(window).on("keydown", function() {
    d3.select(".draggable-rect").remove();
    d3.select(d3.event.view)          // Remove global (internal) drag handlers 
      .on("mousemove.drag", null)
      .on("mouseup.drag", null);
})
```

As is always the case when it comes to fiddling with the inner workings of some library, you have to be cautious not to break other things and to keep in mind that this is in danger of breaking silently with any future release of D3.

Have a look at this working demo:

```js
d3.select("svg").append('rect').attr('class', 'draggable-rect');
                               
d3.select(window).on("keydown", function() {
 d3.select(".draggable-rect").remove();
  d3.select(d3.event.view)
    .on("mousemove.drag", null)
    .on("mouseup.drag", null);
})

d3.select(".draggable-rect")
  .call(d3.drag().on("start", dragstarted)
           .on("drag", dragged)
               .on("end", dragended));

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
 console.log("dragging")
  d3.select(this).attr("x", d3.event.x - 40).attr("y", d3.event.y - 40);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}
```

```css
.test-area {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.draggable-rect {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div class="test-area">
  <svg>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I find it quite odd that this is considered a very rare problem. My application is actually just a labelling website (draw bbox), where the user can switch image and the bboxes (and all event listeners) attached to each image should disappear. Since user can switch image using the keyboard and draw using the mouse. It might happen that the user is dragging the box and switch image using the keyboard. Is d3 not suitable for such use case then? Or is there better way to use d3 such that this will not happen?